# How do I use Django's logger to log a traceback when I tell it to?

Tags: python, django, logging, traceback

```
try:
    print blah
except KeyError:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

I used to debug like this. I'd print to the console. Now, I want to log everything instead of print, since Apache doesn't allow printing.  So, how do I log this entire traceback?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can use python's logging mechanism:

```
import logging
...

logger = logging.getLogger("blabla")
...

try:
    print blah # You can use logger.debug("blah") instead of print
except KeyError:
    logger.exception("An error occurred")
```

This will print the stack trace and will work with apache.

Comment: yes, full stack trace. From the documentation: "Logger.exception() creates a log message similar to Logger.error(). The difference is that Logger.exception() dumps a stack trace along with it.". This is the link to the documentation - http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html

Comment: Where does the log get saved to? You defined logger = logging.getLogger('bla'), but does this save to a specific diretory? A file or database?

Comment: The log is saved to a file (default behavior). You can configure the log file location: LOG_FILENAME = 'example.log' logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME,level=logging.DEBUG), you can find an explanation in the documentation - http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#simple-examples

Comment: @Li. Is there any way to get the full stack into a python object, say a string, instead of logging into a file?

Comment: @Lin In this situation, it's much better to use Django's LOGGING configuration in settings.py and let your handlers/loggers decide where to send the logs.

Comment: To get a stacktrace you can include `exc_info=True` in the args to logger and it'll use the exception in the current context.  `logger.exception` defaults to that being true while `logger.error` defaults to false.  This can be useful if you want to include the stacktrace in a `debug` level logging statement.

Answer (score 8):

If you're running Django's trunk version (or 1.3 when it's released), there are a number of default logging configurations built in which are integrated with Python's standard logging module. For that, all you need to do is `import logging`, call `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` and then call `logger.exception(msg)` and you'll get both your message and a stack trace. Docs for [Django's logging functionality](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/) and [Python's logger.exception method](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.exception) would be handy references.

If you don't want to use Python's logging module, you can also `import sys` and write to `sys.stderr` rather than using print. On the command line this goes to the screen, when running under Apache it'll go into your error logs.

Comment: "then call logger.exception(msg) and you'll get both your message and a stack trace." -  This is a true statement. Thanks for that :).