# DateTimeField received a naive datetime while time zone support is active

Tags: django

Django is giving me some runtime warnings (on code that I didn't write).

How can I get Django to give me a stacktrace, so I can see what is causing these?

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:808: 
RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime (2012-07-19 09:36:16.161479) 
while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From the docs at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/i18n/timezones/#code

During development, you can turn such warnings into exceptions and get a traceback by adding the following to your settings file:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings(
    'error', r"DateTimeField .* received a naive datetime",
    RuntimeWarning, r'django\.db\.models\.fields')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can implement your a log formatter and put trace back for warning messages in the logs using `traceback.print_exception()`.

Refer to Fomatter docs at [FormatException](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.Formatter.formatException)

You can also refer this, [How do I use Django's logger to log a traceback when I tell it to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839762/how-do-i-use-djangos-logger-to-log-a-traceback-when-i-tell-it-to)

Answer (score -2):

This means that you enabled timezone support in django; but you passed it a datetime object that doesn't have any time zone information attached to it.

If you want django's timezone support, then datetime objects used should be timezone aware.

The [documentation on timezone support](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects) provides a way to turn your datetime objects into those with timzeones.

Comment: Thanks, but I know this.  I'm looking for what caused the runtime warning.  This is not the only one...

Answer (score -3):

Django's source tells you what just happened:

```
def get_prep_value(self, value):
    value = self.to_python(value)
    if value is not None and settings.USE_TZ and timezone.is_naive(value):
        # For backwards compatibility, interpret naive datetimes in local
        # time. This won't work during DST change, but we can't do much
        # about it, so we let the exceptions percolate up the call stack.
        warnings.warn(u"DateTimeField received a naive datetime (%s)"
                      u" while time zone support is active." % value,
                      RuntimeWarning)
        default_timezone = timezone.get_default_timezone()
        value = timezone.make_aware(value, default_timezone)
    return value
```

Comment: Thanks, but I know this.  I'm looking for what caused the runtime warning.  This is not the only one...