# Django (django_tables2) ValueError: Expected table or queryset, not str + for loop issue

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-tables2

I have a Django project that is heavily influenced by Mozilla's Django tutorial (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Tutorial_local_library_website). I have modified the `books` to `samples`, and each of these `samples` is affiliated with a researcher/`pi` (aka `author`). I created a separate model called `Variant` which is a a foreignkey for the `Sample` model. As this field will allow multiple variants for each sample, when looking at a detail view of a sample, I would like to display the variants (specific to an individual sample) as a rendered table. I have not been successful in achieving this and I think I am just not quite getting the view nomenclature correct (as well as the language in the html file). My questions are at the end of this post.

Here is my code.

**samples/models.py**

```
class Variant(models.Model):
   gene = models.CharField('Gene', max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
   variant = models.CharField('Variant', max_length=50, blank=True, default='')
   call = models.CharField('Call', max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
   position = models.IntegerField('Position', blank=True, null=True) 

   def __str__(self):
      return f'{self.gene}, {self.position}, {self.variant}, {self.call}'

class Sample(models.Model):
   sample_name = models.CharField('Sample', max_length=16)
   pi = models.ForeignKey(PI, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
   sample_variant = models.ForeignKey(Variant, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True) 
     .
     .
     .
   def __str__(self):
      return self.sample_name

   def get_absolute_url(self):
      return reverse('sample-detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

**tables.py**

```
class SampleTable(tables.Table):
   sample_name = tables.LinkColumn('sample-detail', args=[A('pk')])
   pi = tables.LinkColumn('sample-detail', args=[A('pk')])

   class Meta:
      model = Sample
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
class PISampleTable(tables.Table):
   sample_name = tables.LinkColumn('sample-detail', args=[A('pk')])

   class Meta:
      model = Sample
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------

...
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
class VariantTable(tables.Table):
   gene = tables.LinkColumn('sample-detail', args=[A('pk')])

   class Meta:
      model = Variant
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am not certain if setting gene (Variant field) as I did is copacetic.

**samples/views.py**

```
class SampleListView(generic.ListView):
   model = Sample
   paginate_by = 100

@login_required
def sam(request):
   table = SampleTable(Sample.objects.all())
   RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
   return render(request, 'samples/sample_list.html', {'sam': table}) 
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class SampleDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Sample
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    ...
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class VariantListView(generic.ListView):
   model = Variant
   paginate_by = 100

@login_required
def var(request):
   #table = VariantTable(Variant.objects.filter(pi=pk))
   table = VariantTable(Variant.objects.all())
   RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
   return render(request, 'samples/sample_detail.html', {'var': table}) 
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**samples/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [ 
   path('', views.index, name='index'),
   path('samples/', views.sam, name='sam'),
   path('sample/<int:pk>', views.SampleDetailView.as_view(), name='sample-detail'),
   path('pi/', views.pi_table, name='pi_table'),
   path('pi/<int:pk>', views.pi_view, name='pi-detail'),
   path('samples/new', views.pi_new, name='pi_new'),
   path('samples/new_sample', views.sample_new, name='sample_new'),
   #path('samples/', views.var, name='var'),
   #path('samples/<int:pk>', views.var, name='var'),
   path('samples/', views.VariantListView.as_view(), name='var'),
]
```

**samples/templates/samples/sample_detail.html**

```
 {% extends "base_generic.html" %}
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}

{% block content %}
   <h1>Sample: {{ sample.sample_name }}</h1>

   <p><strong>PI:</strong> <a href="{% url 'pi-detail' sample.pi.pk %}">{{ sample.pi }}</a></p>
   ...
   <h3>Variant Results</h3>
   <p><strong>(gene, position, variant, call):</strong> {{ sample.sample_variant }}</p> <!-- this works, but only last item in list-->


  <p><strong>Variant:</strong> {% for variant in sample.sample_variant.all %} {{ variant }}{% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}{% endfor %}</p>

  {% if sample.sample_variant %}
  <ul>

   {% for variant in variant_list %}
     <li> <a href="{{ variant.get_absolute_url }}">{{ variant.gene }}</a> ({{variant.call}})</li>
   {% endfor %}
  </ul>
  {% else %}
    <p>There are no variants for this sample.</p>                                                                                                                                    

  {% endif %}       

{% render_table var %}

{% endblock %}
```

To test it out, I have one sample to which I have added two variants -- however, only the last variant is displayed from this (understandable):

```
<p><strong>(gene, position, variant, call):</strong> {{ sample.sample_variant }}
```

The loop code is something I was playing with but it does not work at all, and if I keep the `{% render_table var %}` line in there I will get this error:

```
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    content = template.render(context, self._request)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django_tables2/templatetags/django_tables2.py", line 148, in render
    raise ValueError("Expected table or queryset, not {}".format(klass))
ValueError: Expected table or queryset, not str
```

I understand that the error caused by my passing a string instead of a queryset/table class object, but I have not figured out how to address it.

The django_tables2 version is current and is rendering other tables with no issues.

1. I linked the `gene` to a column in a similar fashion as I did for fields in other models (`sample_name` and the `pi`) -- is it correct?
2. How could I have arranged the for loop to correctly display all the variants in the list?
3. What do I need to change in (assuming) the views.py file to correctly render the `var` table?
4. I am not convinced I have correctly listed the path (I dabbled with several variations to no success) in urls.py, how should it be properly structured if incorrect?

Much gratitude and appreciation for any assistance.

Comment: Please post the *full* traceback.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem If I used this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839762/how-do-i-use-djangos-logger-to-log-a-traceback-when-i-tell-it-to, which file should I add it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok -- many thanks to a friend (AR) who helped me track down the error.

The first issue is that I had the relationship incorrect; the foreignkey needed to be in the `Variant` model, not the `Sample` model (`sample_variant` in `Sample` model was deleted).

models.py

```
class Variant(models.Model):                                                              
   gene = models.CharField('Gene', max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
   nucleotide_variant = models.CharField('Variant', max_length=50, blank=True, default='')   call = models.CharField('Call', max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
   position = models.IntegerField('Position', blank=True, null=True) 
   sample_n = models.ForeignKey(Sample, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

   class Meta:
      ordering = ('sample_n', 'gene', 'position', 'nucleotide_variant', 'call')

   def __str__(self):
      return f'{self.sample_n}, {self.gene}, {self.position}, {self.nucleotide_variant}, {self.call}'
```

The next thing is that I changed the field `variant` to `nucleotide_variant`. This may be unnecessary, but it made it clearer for me.

views.py

```
class VariantListView(generic.ListView):
   model = Variant
   paginate_by = 100 

@login_required
def var(request):
   variant = Variant.objects.get(pk = pk) 
   table = VariantTable(Variant.objects.filter(variant=pk))
   RequestConfig(request).configure(table)                                                
   return render(request, 'samples/sample_detail.html', {'variant': variant, 'var': table})
```

urls.py

```
path('samples/', views.var, name='var'),
```

html

```
   <h3>Variant Results</h3>
   {% render_table sample.variant_set.all %}
```

Problem solved, table rendered.